# Markdown in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, markdown

Is there a way to parse Markdown in React using Typescript?

I am trying to do things like:

```
import * as ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
// OR
import ReactMarkdown = require('react-markdown')
```

But Typescript can't fint module 'react-markdown' as it's not defined:

> Error: TS2307: Cannot find module 'react-markdown'.

How can I define the module and use it as a React component?

Comment: Do you have `react-markdown` somewhere? Have you installed it using npm? Have you downloaded it?

Comment: It's not an issue with the actual packages, you're just missing the declaration files so TypeScript doesn't know about the module. Sadly, there doesn't seem to be one in DefinitelyTyped, so I guess you need to create *react-markdown.d.ts* yourself.

Comment: Do you know how to make a such file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem by using `commonmark` package instead. They have typings and everything needed for my environment. Here is my implementation:

```
import { HtmlRenderer, Parser } from 'commonmark'

export class MyComponent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  private post: string

  constructor () {
    super()
    let parser = new Parser()
    let renderer = new HtmlRenderer()
    this.post = renderer.render(parser.parse("**works** like a charm!"))
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: this.post} } />
    )
  }
}
```

Also, do not forget to add the typings for `commonmark`:

```
$ typings install --global --save dt~commonmark
```

Thanks to the people who tried to help!

Comment: Using dangerouslySetInnerHTML is not a secure way to render HTML, ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml. Use libreary such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63111085/6133559