# How do I load a markdown file into a react component?

Tags: reactjs, markdown

How would I load a .md markdown file into a react component? I have tried so many npm libraries through google searches and I cant find a good solution.

[image: Code image]

I want to load the .md file something like:

```js
render() {
    <div>
        <MarkDown src="about.md" />
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I use [marked](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked) ([GitHub](https://github.com/chjj/marked)).

I first import it like this:

```js
import marked from "marked";
```

I then fetch my *.md file within React's `componentDidMount` event and store it in my component's state using `marked(text)` (where `text` is the response):

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const readmePath = require("./Readme.md");

  fetch(readmePath)
    .then(response => {
      return response.text()
    })
    .then(text => {
      this.setState({
        markdown: marked(text)
      })
    })
}
```

...and finally I render it on the page using the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute:

```js
render() {
  const { markdown } = this.state;

  return (
    <section>
      <article dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: markdown}}></article>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Comment: Tried import "marked" and Typescript couldnt find declaration file

Comment: I'm not familiar with TypeScript, but you'll need to install the package first. `npm install marked --save` should do the trick.

Comment: Ah, found out i needed to install a type definition to make Typescript happy. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/marked. Thank you my friend

Comment: You also need to initiate state via construct(props) method.

Comment: doesn't work for me ./src/pages/about.md
Module parse failed: /Users/me/myproject/src/pages/about.md Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)

Comment: I want to load all markdown files inside folder (preview only). Any tip?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/53975297/7784399 instead of this. It doesn't use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute.

Answer (score 75):

A full working example with `react-markdown`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import termsFrPath from './Terms.fr.md'

class Terms extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { terms: null }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch(termsFrPath).then((response) => response.text()).then((text) => {
      this.setState({ terms: text })
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content">
        <ReactMarkdown source={this.state.terms} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Terms
```

Comment: solid. Thanks for the detail. How do you deal with the redirect its taking you to?

Comment: I get `Cannot find module './Terms.fr.md' or its corresponding type declarations` error. Using `const termsFrPath = require './Terms.fr.md'` works.

Comment: if you are using typescript juste create a declaration.d.ts file at the root of your project and add : `declare module '*.md'` before importing it

Comment: this used to work especially using /with-html v9 however is a nightmare

Answer (score 34):

You should use [react-markdown](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown) instead of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42928796/7784399), this solution doesn't use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppMarkdown from './App.md';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { markdown: '' };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // Get the contents from the Markdown file and put them in the React state, so we can reference it in render() below.
    fetch(AppMarkdown).then(res => res.text()).then(text => this.setState({ markdown: text }));
  }

  render() {
    const { markdown } = this.state;
    return <ReactMarkdown source={markdown} />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

**App.md**

```
# React & Markdown App
* Benefits of using React... but...
* Write layout in Markdown!
```

Comment: This also doesn't work - `Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:4)`

Comment: I think you need to add in the stuff you must have somewhere else that allows MD files to be processed as an import like a JS file would be

Comment: @ToniLeigh Can you please provide steps

Comment: @Coderboi loader? what do you mean? package manager? NPM.

Comment: problem arises when you dont whitelist ".md" extension in raw-loader ,(yes that npm package raw-loader)...putting that in webpack solved my case.

Answer (score 17):

Similar to @Xing-Han-Lu's answer but with react Markdown. The concept uses `useEffect` to load up the file then adds it to state using the `useState` hook where it's accessible to `reactMarkdown`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";
import file from "./md/posts.md";

export default function () {
  const [markdown, setMarkdown] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(file)
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((text) => setMarkdown(text));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <ReactMarkdown source={markdown} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 16):

[markdown-to-jsx](https://github.com/probablyup/markdown-to-jsx) provides very efficeint functionality to interact with markdown in React component.

It allows replacing/overriding of any HTML element with your Custom Component for markdown, [here is the doc](https://github.com/probablyup/markdown-to-jsx#optionsoverrides---override-any-html-tags-representation).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Markdown from 'markdown-to-jsx';
import README from './README.md'

class PageComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { md: "" }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch(README)
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((md) => {
        this.setState({ md })
      })
  }

  render() {

    let { md } = this.state

    return (
      <div className="post">
        <Markdown children={md}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default PageComponent
```

#### Edit 2nd Aug'21

###### Functional Component

```
const PageComponent = ()=> {

    let [ content, setContent] = useState({md: ""});

    useEffect(()=> {
        fetch(README)
            .then((res) => res.text())
            .then((md) => {
                setContent({ md })
            })
    }, [])

    return (
      <div className="post">
        <Markdown children={content.md}/>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This produces: Module not found: Can't resolve './README.md'

Comment: Is there a custom loader necessary like https://github.com/peerigon/markdown-loader/blob/master/example/webpack.config.js ?

Comment: I think you need a file loader, you can also try md-loader aswell.

Comment: I have used it in create-react-app without loader.

Comment: ppl who are getting this error , just add .md extension inside you raw-loader module in webpack

Comment: Worked out of the box. +1 since `markdown-to-jsx` also handles tables.

Comment: `componentWillMount` has since been [deprecated](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) and console displays warnings.

Answer (score 9):

#### Approach using webpack loader

Install **raw-loader**

```sh
npm install raw-loader --save-dev
```

Update **webpack.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ...
      {
        test: /\.md$/,
        use: "raw-loader",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Create markdown file (say `App.md`)

```
# React & Markdown App

- Benefits of using React... but...
- Write layout in Markdown!
```

Import `App.md` and use it in React component.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import AppMarkdown from './App.md';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactMarkdown children={`${AppMarkdown}`} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 5):

Where I struggled with all these answers is the loading of the markdown file into frontend React. They make some kind of assumption as to what you're using.

For the world of React I would recommend [MDX](https://mdxjs.com/).

I'm using it with Next.js, but MDX is [compatible with lots of Javascript bundlers and React libraries](https://mdxjs.com/docs/getting-started/#quick-start) and does a lot of work to handle the bit that lots of people ignore here which is the loading in of non-JS syntax.

> **Note:** MDX sticks more to the original style of Markdown without tables or the funky extras. If you want extra stuff you need to [install MDX plugins](https://mdxjs.com/docs/extending-mdx/#using-plugins)

See these references:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52265474/327074
- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/next-mdx
- https://mdxjs.com/docs/using-mdx/#mdx-content

Install with:

```
npm install @next/mdx @mdx-js/loader
```

`next.config.js`:

For [Next.js integration](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/next-mdx#usage) we don't have to touch the webpack config just wrap our existing `next.config.js` with a `withMDX` function:

```js
/**
 * @link https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/next-mdx#usage
 */
const withMDX = require('@next/mdx')()

// your existing next.config.js
const nextConfig = {
   ...
}

module.exports = withMDX(nextConfig)
```

`about.mdx`:

Read more about this in [Using MDX docs](https://mdxjs.com/docs/using-mdx/#how-mdx-works)

```markdown
# Just some regular markdown

any old rubbish **will do**

You can stick extra <Funky /> stuff in here but *regular markdown* works fine
```

`AboutPage.jsx`:

Note below how now you don't need to do any `fetch`ing or `useEffect`, it's simply like loading in a JSON or JS file.

```
import React from "react";
import AboutMarkdown from "./about.mdx";

const AboutPage () => (
    <AboutMarkdown />
);
```

Comment: Just a note: the latest version of MDX loader doesn't work on react apps created using Create React App (CRA), as noted here https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx/discussions/1870. 
 
One suggestion to fix it involves downgrading `@mdx/loader` and `react-scripts` dependencies, which can be undesirable in context of security concerns.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Install react-markdown**

`npm i react-markdown`

**2. Use it in my react functional component**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import bookPath from './../Markdown/book.md'

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(bookPath)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((md) => {
            setText(md)
        })
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <ReactMarkdown children={text} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyComponent
```

Comment: cant get this to work in production on amplify

Answer (score 1):

For **Typescript + react** please follow below steps:

1. Create one **type definition** (*index.d.ts*) file in one of the project directory and put the following code.

```
declare module "*.md";
```

2. Add `tsconfig.json -> CompilerOptions -> typeRoots` as following

```
{
     "compilerOptions": {
         ...
         "typeRoots": [ "<types-directory-created-in-#1>", "./node_modules/@types"],
         ...
     }
}
```

3. Install two libraries [showdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/showdown) and [html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser)

`yarn add showdown` or `npm install showdown`

`yarn add html-react-parser` or `npm install html-react-parser`

4. In your component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import showdown from 'showdown';
import parse from 'html-react-parser';
import readme from 'path/filename.md';

export default function ComponentName() {
    const [html, setHTML] = useState("");

    //Use componentDidMount(): if class based component to load md file
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(readme)
            .then(data => data.text())
            .then(text => {
                const converter = new showdown.Converter();
                setHTML(converter.makeHtml(text));
            })
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>{parse(html)}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I slightly modified this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52232940/13837091) to use hooks and `useEffect` (which is different from `componentWillUpdate` but still works). If you built your app with create-react-app and you have a markdown document called `document.md`, you can build your app in the following way:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Markdown from 'markdown-to-jsx';
import mdDocument from './document.md';

const App = () => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(mdDocument)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(md => { setContent(md) })
  })

  return (
    <div><Markdown children={content} /></div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Updated Version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42928796/12271495

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { marked } from "marked";

class App extends Component {
  state = {markdown: ""}
  componentDidMount() {
    const readmePath = require("./blogs/README.md");

    fetch(readmePath)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.text();
      })
      .then((text) => {
        this.setState({
          markdown: marked.parse(text),
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { markdown } = this.state;

    return (
      <section>
        <article dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: markdown }}></article>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Webpack (i.e. [Electron React Boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate)) then you can save a few steps by using Webpack loaders.

```
npm i -D html-loader markdown-loader marked
```

In webpack.config.renderer.dev.js:

```
import marked from 'marked';
const markdownRenderer = new marked.Renderer();

....

  // Markdown
  {
    test: /\.md$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'html-loader'
      },
      {
        loader: 'markdown-loader',
        options: {
          pedantic: true,
          renderer: markdownRenderer
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Then, in the React component it's simply a require and setting the HTML.

```
import knownIssues from '../assets/md/known-issues.md';
....
<p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: knownIssues }} />
```

Lastly, Flow will report an error (it still works) when importing the markdown file. Add this to .flowconfig to make Flow treat md files as string assets (care of Webpack):

```
module.name_mapper.extension='md' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/internals/flow/WebpackAsset.js.flow'
```

Comment: thank you! this work for me, and I think that using loader is better than markdown rendering in browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the above suggestions and deduced that after running a command

```
> npm install markdown
```

```
import ReactMarkdown from 'markdown';
```

it finally worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I wanted it to work using dynamic imports using [react-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-markdown). My *general* code is below, you'll have to add a useEffect to call the function and put a reference to the state variable in the function return:

```
  const [displayElement, setDisplayElement] = useState(null);

  //Get markdown file
  const fetchMarkdown = async (location) => {
    console.log("MD location: ", location);
    try {
      //I figured out readmePath.default using print statements, left there in case
      //someone wants them
      const readmePath = await require("" + location);
      //console.log(readmePath);
      const response = await fetch(readmePath.default);
      //console.log("response => ", response);
      const text = await response.text();
      //console.log(text);

      // the state variable I am setting the markdown into, in my render function 
      // I have {displayElement}.
      setDisplayElement(
        <div className={styles.markdownContainer}>
          <ReactMarkdown children={text} />
        </div>
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Markdown file: couldn't read =>", location, e);
    }
  };
```

The addition of the empty string in  `const readmePath = await require("" + location);` is required (*hehe*). I got that from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57939804/11072972). I don't know why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to put the Markdown in a .js file, using the backtick ` character to enclose the Markdown as an untagged template literal.  Like this:

```
const MD = `
**TERMS OF SERVICE**

Last Modified: 30 November 2021...`

export default MD
```

Then you can `import` it like any other module.