# Import markdown files as strings in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, next.js

How can I import markdown files as strings in [Next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/) to work on client and server side?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can configure your Next.js webpack loaders to load markdown files and return them as strings, for example:

**`docs/home.md`**

```
# Home

This is my **awesome** home!
```

**`pages/index.js`**

```
import React from 'react';
import markdown from '../docs/home.md';

export default () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <pre>{markdown}</pre>
      <small><i>Import and render markdown using Next.js</i></small>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**`package.json`**

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "next": "^4.2.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0"
  }
}
```

**`next.config.js`**

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    return Object.assign({}, config, {
      externals: Object.assign({}, config.externals, {
        fs: 'fs',
      }),
      module: Object.assign({}, config.module, {
        rules: config.module.rules.concat([
          {
            test: /\.md$/,
            loader: 'emit-file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'dist/[path][name].[ext]',
            },
          },
          {
            test: /\.md$/,
            loader: 'raw-loader',
          }
        ]),
      }),
    });
  }
};
```

When running:

```
$ npm run dev
```

Something like this would appear:

[image: example preview]

With the markdown string you can do whatever you would like. For example, process it with [marksy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marksy).

Answer (score 11):

**Updates: `emit-file-loader` not strictly required, `raw-loader` deprecated in favor of asset modules**

Some updates to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47954368/895245 possibly due to newer developments:

- asset modules superseded `raw-loader`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47954368/895245 No need to install any extra packages for that anyomore
- `emit-file-loader` does not seem necessary anymore, not sure if it was needed, or if it is for something more specialized

so we can simplify things slightly to:

pages/index.js

```
import world from '../world.md'

export default function IndexPage() {
  return <div>hello {world}</div>
}
```

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.md$/,
        // This is the asset module.
        type: 'asset/source',
      }
    )
    return config
  },
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  }
}
```

world.md

```markdown
my md world
```

**Getting it to work from Typescript**

Unfortunately both `raw-loader` and asset modules require a bit more work from typescript: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader/issues/56#issuecomment-423640398 You have to create a file:

global.d.ts

```
declare module '*.md'
```

Otherwise the import will fail with:

```
Type error: Cannot find module '../world.md' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Full example:

global.d.ts

```
declare module '*.md'
```

pages/index.tsx

```
import world from '../world.md'

export default function IndexPage() {
  const what: string = 'my'
  // Would fail on build as desired.
  // const what2: int = 'world2'
  return <div>hello {what} {world}</div>
}
```

next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    config.module.rules.push(
      {
        test: /\.md$/,
        type: 'asset/source',
      }
    )
    return config
  },
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "type-check": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "v12.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "12.12.21",
    "@types/react": "17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "typescript": "4.0"
  }
}
```

world.md

```
my md world
```

Answer (score 9):

Just install `raw-loader`

```
npm install --save raw-loader
```

then edit your next.config.js

```
webpack: (config) => {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.md$/,
    use: 'raw-loader',
  });
  return config;
},
```

Comment: Selected answer did not work for me. This did though!

Comment: npm install --save or --save-dev? I think it should be --save-dev

Comment: It seems [`raw-loader` has been deprecated](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader).

Answer (score 8):

Quicker and "Next.js way" is to use plugin **next-mdx**

Documentation: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/next-mdx

```
// next.config.js
const withMDX = require('@zeit/next-mdx')({
  extension: /\.mdx?$/
})
module.exports = withMDX({
  pageExtensions: ['js', 'jsx', 'mdx']
})
```

Comment: Documentation is now located at https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/next-mdx