# How to import a markdown file in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

So, I'm trying to display pure markdown in my NextJS Typescript page, I tried it:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import markdown from "./assets/1.md";

const Post1 = () => {
  return <>{markdown}</>;
};

export default Post1;
```

But I got it:

```
./pages/blog/assets/1.md
Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> # Apresentations
| 
| Hi, my name is Vitor Koch
```

I already created the markdown.d.ts file

**Obs.: I don't want to convert md to jsx, just want to display it, I already did it in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/vitorkoch/d24eac6765c425e56dcae6baee2867f9)**

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928530/how-do-i-load-a-markdown-file-into-a-react-component

Comment: @Sovari no, a don't want to convert the markdown, just show it purely

Comment: if you needn't format md file, just use `<pre>{markdown}</pre>`

Comment: @DaniilLoban same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47954367/import-markdown-files-as-strings-in-next-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh now I get it. You could try this then:

```js
return <>{JSON.stringify(markdown, 2, null)}</>;
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/LrkWMKM
and same error

Comment: You'll probably need to incorporate a `markdown-loader` into your webpack config first https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-loader

Comment: And here's how you extend your webpack config with an additional loader https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config

Comment: TYYYYY I WANNA KISS YOU

Comment: I'm so happy it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

1. Install markdown parsing library (`react-markdown` or other, I will use `marked`)
2. Place your `markdown_file.md` file in `/public` folder
3. Read file on the server `/pages/your_page.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { marked } from 'marked';

export default function YourPage(props: { html: string }) {
    const { html } = props;
    return (
        <div>
            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
        </div>
    );
}

const filePath = join(process.cwd(), 'public', 'markdown_file.md');

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
    return {
        props: {
            html: marked.parse(fileContent),
        },
    };
}
```