# react native (expo) load markdown files

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm having some troubles loading markdown files (`.md`) into my react native (non-detached expo project).

Found this awesome package that allows me to render it. But can't figure out how to load the local `.md` file as a string.

```
import react from 'react';
import {PureComponent} from 'react-native';
import Markdown from 'react-native-markdown-renderer';

const copy = `# h1 Heading 8-)

| Option | Description |
| ------ | ----------- |
| data   | path to data files to supply the data that will be passed into templates. |
| engine | engine to be used for processing templates. Handlebars is the default. |
| ext    | extension to be used for dest files. |
`;

export default class Page extends PureComponent {

  static propTypes = {};
  static defaultProps = {};

  render() {
    return (
        <Markdown>{copy}</Markdown>
    );
  }
}
```

---

BTW: I tried googling, but can't get the suggestions to work

https://forums.expo.io/t/loading-non-media-assets-markdown/522/2?u=norfeldtconsulting

I tried the suggested answers for reactjs on SO, but the problem seems to be that it only accepts `.js` and `.json` files

Comment: Check this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928530/how-do-i-load-a-markdown-file-into-a-react-component. This already has an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load a markdown file into a react component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928530/how-do-i-load-a-markdown-file-into-a-react-component)

Comment: I have tested these answers and this question is not a duplicate since it seems to work differently in react native expo.

Comment: @Think-Twice I have updated my question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks to @Filipe's response, I got some guidance and got a working example that will fit your needs.

In my case, I had a `.md` file on the `assets/markdown/` folder, the file is called `test-1.md`

The trick is to get a local `url` for the file, and then use the `fetch` API to get its content as a `string`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Markdown from 'react-native-markdown-renderer';
const copy = `# h1 Heading 8-)

| Option | Description |
| ------ | ----------- |
| data   | path to data files to supply the data that will be passed into templates. |
| engine | engine to be used for processing templates. Handlebars is the default. |
| ext    | extension to be used for dest files. |
`;

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      copy: copy
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchLocalFile();
  }

  fetchLocalFile = async () => {
    let file = Expo.Asset.fromModule(require("./assets/markdown/test-1.md"))
    await file.downloadAsync() // Optional, saves file into cache
    file = await fetch(file.uri)
    file = await file.text()

    this.setState({copy: file});
  }


  render() {
    return (
        <Markdown>{this.state.copy}</Markdown>
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: In order to get get rid of the error

> Unable to resolve "./assets/markdown/test-1.md" from "App.js"

you would need to add the `packagerOpts` part of @Filipe's snippet into your `app.json` file.

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    ...
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "packagerOpts": {
      "assetExts": ["md"]
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

EDIT 2:
Answering to @Norfeldt's comment:
Although I use `react-native init` when working on my own projects, and I'm therefore not very familiar with Expo, I got this Expo Snack that might have some answers for you: https://snack.expo.io/Hk8Ghxoqm.

It won't work on the expo snack because of the issues reading non-JSON files, but you can test it locally if you wish.

Using `file.downloadAsync()` will prevent the app making XHR calls to a server where your file is hosted within that app session (as long as the user does not close and re-open the app).

If you change the file or modify the file (simulated with a call to `Expo.FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync()`), it should display the updated as long as your component re-renders and re-downloads the file.

This will happen every time your app is closed and re-open, as the `file.localUri` is not persisted per sessions as far as I'm concerned, so your app will always call `file.downloadAsync()` at least once every time it's opened. So you should have no problems displaying an updated file.

I also took some time to test the speed of using `fetch` versus using `Expo.FileSystem.readAsStringAsync()`, and they were on average the same. Often times `Expo.FileSystem.readAsStringAsync` was ~200 ms faster, but it 's not a deal breaker in my opinion.

I created three different methods for fetching the same file.

```
export default class MarkdownRenderer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      copy: ""
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetch()
  }

  fetch = () => {
    if (this.state.copy) {
      // Clear current state, then refetch data
      this.setState({copy: ""}, this.fetch)
      return;
    }
    let asset = Expo.Asset.fromModule(md)
    const id = Math.floor(Math.random()  * 100) % 40;
    console.log(`[${id}] Started fetching data`, asset.localUri)
    let start = new Date(), end;

    const save = (res) => {
      this.setState({copy: res})
      let end = new Date();
      console.info(`[${id}] Completed fetching data in ${(end - start) / 1000} seconds`)
    }

    // Using Expo.FileSystem.readAsStringAsync.
    // Makes it a single asynchronous call, but must always use localUri
    // Therefore, downloadAsync is required
    let method1 = () => {
      if (!asset.localUri) {
        asset.downloadAsync().then(()=>{
          Expo.FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(asset.localUri).then(save)
        })
      } else {
        Expo.FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(asset.localUri).then(save)
      }
    }

    // Use fetch ensuring the usage of a localUri
    let method2 = () => {
      if (!asset.localUri) {
        asset.downloadAsync().then(()=>{
          fetch(asset.localUri).then(res => res.text()).then(save)
        })
      } else {
        fetch(asset.localUri).then(res => res.text()).then(save)
      }
    }

    // Use fetch but using `asset.uri` (not the local file)
    let method3 = () => {
      fetch(asset.uri).then(res => res.text()).then(save)
    }

    // method1()
    // method2()
    method3()
  }

  changeText = () => {
    let asset = Expo.Asset.fromModule(md)
    Expo.FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(asset.localUri, "Hello World");
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView style={{maxHeight: "90%"}}>
          <Button onPress={this.fetch} title="Refetch"/>
          <Button onPress={this.changeText} title="Change Text"/>
            <Markdown>{this.state.copy}</Markdown>
        </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Just alternate between the three to see the difference in the logs.

Comment: Thank you so much! I clearly didn't have the skills to figure out how to fetch and extract the text out of it. Do the `file.downloadAsync()` mean that it won't download the file each time I use the App? What if I change the content of the markdown after deploying and do an OTA - with it use the cached file or detect that it has been changed and cache the new one instead?

Comment: Tried my best to answer your questions in my updated answer

Comment: In order for this to work though, you also need to modify your metro.config.js file:
`const defaultAssetExts = require("metro-config/src/defaults/defaults").assetExts;

module.exports = {

  resolver: {
    //...
    assetExts: [
      ...defaultAssetExts,
      "md"
    ],
    //...
};`

Comment: If anyone see's this answer with expo 40, it's not going to work - check out my answer below.

Comment: For newer expo versions, check the following https://docs.expo.dev/guides/customizing-metro/ to allow MD extension in `metro.config.js`. The file must be imported statically, dynamic use of `require('file.md')` did not work for me yet.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, this cannot be done within expo. I use react-native and run it on my mobile for development.

`react-native` use Metro as the default bundler, which also suffers from similar problems. You have to use [haul](https://github.com/callstack/haul) bundler instead.

`npm install --save-dev haul`

`npx haul init`

`npx haul start --platform android`

In a seperate terminal run `react-native run-android`. This would use `haul` instead of `metro` to bundle the files.

To add the markdown file, install [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) and edit the `haul.config.js` file. `raw-loader` imports any file as a string.

Customise your `haul.config.js` to look something like this:

```
import { createWebpackConfig } from "haul";
export default {
 webpack: env => {
  const config = createWebpackConfig({
    entry: './index.js',
  })(env);
  config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.md$/,
      use: 'raw-loader'
   })
  return config;
 }
};
```

Now you can import the markdown file by using `const example = require('./example.md')`

Haul supports webpack configuration so you can add any custom babel transform you want.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to try and answer my question. I never knew of `haul` - seems pretty interesting. I would like to avoid ejecting from expo (I like the OTA feature), so I'll keep the question open a little longer and if no better answer comes - then I'll mark your answer as the answer.

Comment: thanks to you, I never had to edit the `haul.config.js` file, and now I know how to :)

Comment: I'm so glad that you got something out of it as well. Again, thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly where the problem lies, but I added html files to the project, and I'd imagine it would be very similar.

Inside your app.json, try adding these fields:

```
"assetBundlePatterns": [
  "assets/**",
],
"packagerOpts": {
  "assetExts": ["md"]
},
```

The `packagerOpts` makes it so the standalone will bundle the .md files. I'd imagine you already have an assets folder, but just in case you don't, you will need one.

Then, on `AppLoading`, loading the assets with `Asset.loadAsync` might not be needed, but it's a good idea to rule out. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v30.0.0/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets) on how to use it.

When importing the file, there are three ways you might want to do so, that change depending on the environment. I'll copy this excerpt from my [Medium article](https://medium.com/@filipedegrazia/embedding-a-local-website-on-your-expo-react-native-project-eea322738872):

> In the simulator, you can access any file in the project. Thus, `source={require(./pathToFile.html)}` works. However, when you build a standalone, it doesn’t work quite in the same way. I mean, at least for android it doesn’t. The android webView doesn’t recognise `asset:///` uris for some reason. You have to get the `file:///` path. Thankfully, that is very easy. The assets are bundled inside `file:///android_asset` (Careful, don’t write assets), and `Expo.Asset.fromModule(require(‘./pathToFile.html')).localUri` returns `asset:///nameOfFile.html`. But that’s not all. For the first few times, this uri will be correct. However, after a while, it changes into another file scheme, and can’t be accessed in the same way. Instead, you’ll have to access the localUri directly. Thus, the complete solution is:

```
/* Outside of return */
const { localUri } = Expo.Asset.fromModule(require('./pathToFile.html'));
/* On the webView */
source={
  Platform.OS === ‘android’
  ? {
    uri: localUri.includes('ExponentAsset')
      ? localUri
      : ‘file:///android_asset/’ + localUri.substr(9),
  }
  : require(‘./pathToFile.html’)
}
```

> (A constant part of the uri is `ExponentAsset`, that’s why I chose to check if that was part of it)

That should probably solve your problem. If it doesn't, comment what's going wrong and I'll try to help you further. Cheers!

Comment: I might be stupid, but I don't know how to read the file content. The package I'm trying to use don't have a source prop but expect me to drop it as a string. Doing a `console.log(Expo.Asset.fromModule(require('./pathToFile.html')))` reveals no raw content..

Comment: Extracting the `uri` allows me to "open" the file in a browser via `Linking.openURL(uri)`

Comment: `downloadCallbacks: []
downloaded: false
downloading: false
hash: "43d299a4986521da6b28a00eb764b2a7"
localUri: null
name: "C05"
type: "md"
uri: "http://localhost:19001/assets/assets/markdown/C05.md?platform=ios&hash=43d299a4986521da6b28a00eb764b2a7"`

Comment: Check my answer, it should answer your questions.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I didn't take a look at the library you were using. @Luiz Rizo's answer should do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load `.md` file with react-native cli (without expo). I've got a solution for you)

1. Add https://github.com/feats/babel-plugin-inline-import to your project
2. Add config `.babelrc` file with code inside:

```
{
   "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
   "plugins": [
       [
           "inline-import",
           {
               "extensions": [".md", ".txt"]
           }
       ],
       [
           "module-resolver",
           {
               "root": ["./src"],
               "alias": {}
           }
       ]
   ]
}
```

3. Add to your `metro.config.js` such code

```
const metroDefault = require('metro-config/src/defaults/defaults.js');
...
  resolver: {
    sourceExts: metroDefault.sourceExts.concat(['md', 'txt']),
  }
....
```

4. Reload your app

Comment: This is pretty great. Confirmed working for importing .md in a non Expo app using rn-cli. Thanks for sharing.