# Load a markdown file in Expo 40+ using typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

In Expo 40, I need to load markdown files from my local bundle. I'm also using typescript.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571450/react-native-expo-load-markdown-files) describing a solution, but the `assetsExt` App.json key doesn't seem to work anymore.

I've tried following the typescript tips to add a declaration and add it to my tsconfig, and that lets typescript find it but my when I load my react-native app, it still does not resolve the app:

```
Unable to resolve module ./../../../assets/SOME_MARDOWN.md from /app/xxxx/SOME_COMPONENT.tsx:
None of these files exist:
...
```

Answer (score 2):

In Expo 40 - here was how I was able to get it running!
[Expo website source without typescript.](https://docs.expo.io/guides/assets/#customizing-supported-asset-extensions)

**Note** you'll have to put the files in the `assets` directory, and make sure your `app.json` specifies all of the needed extensions, mine includes everything: `"assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],`

First, I'll split it into two parts - getting Expo to work, then getting typescript to work.

Expo was simple, but only once I realized it was the issue. I followed the above guide. In summary:

1. `expo install @expo/metro-config`
2. create a `metro.config.js` and call the `push` method with whatever extension you are trying to add, in my case it was `md` (markdown):

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config');

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push('md');

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```

3. Reset cache on expo (shift + r in the terminal window running it, on Mac)

Typescript (4) was documented elsewhere:

1. Create a declaration (`*.d.ts`) file, specifying markdown as a valid extension: `declare module "*.<SOME_COOL_FILE_EXTENSION>"`
2. Make sure that file was in one of my `tsconfig.json` root directories (which are listed in the `compilationOptions` -> `"include"` key).
3. Add that file to `typeRoot` under `compilationOptions` in `tsconfig.json`
4. import/require the `md` in my component

For me these steps ended up being:

1. add a file in `./app/declaration.d.ts` containing just: `declare module "*.md"`
2. My `"include"` had the `app` directory in it, and looked like this:   `"include": ["App.js", "app", "test", "storybook"]`
3. I added this to `compilationOptions`: `"typeRoots":["./app/declaration.d.ts"],`
4. `import newborn from './../../../assets/resources/MY_MD_DOC.md'`

Tada!