# Create a loop to import files dynamically in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Consider I have a folder with `.md` files like this:

```
/static/blog/
  example_title.md
  another_example.md
  three_examples.md
```

and I have an array including all titles:

```
const blogEntries = ["example_title", "another_example", "three_examples"]
```

in my component I want to `import` all of them, notice that there could be fewer or more.

Is there any way to dynamically import them similar to:

```
for (let entry in blogEntries) {
  import `Markdown_${entry}` from `/static/blog/${entry}.md`
}
```

and later in my render I can do:

```
<Markdown_three_examples />
```

the above obviously would not work, but I'm looking for a way to achieve similar.

Comment: When you build a react app, all your import / export stuff is converted into one big js file. There's no way to import stuff dynamically because babel can't build that into its file. The solution is to build a Markdown component and `fetch()` the md file from the server when it has mounted.

Comment: @ChrisG can you give an example as answer?

Comment: What part do you need help with? In `componentDidMount()`, use `fetch()` to load the Markdown file. Set its content as part of your state so it gets rendered. Implement the loop by rendering multiple components, using your file array and `map()`.

Comment: Two people have now suggested using `import()`, which is not required to do this at all, and imo takes the question strictly at face value while ignoring the bigger picture. Here's my take: https://codesandbox.io/s/l2jlq3j78m

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import) - `import()`. As the name implies, they work during runtime, and can have dynamic urls.

Note: currently they are [supported natively](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import) by Chrome and Safari, but not by firefox, IE, and Edge. However, you can use webpack to solve that.

```
const blogEntries = ["example_title", "another_example", "three_examples"]

const loadEntries = (entries) =>
  Promise.all(entries.map((entry) => import(`/static/blog/${entry}.md`)));

loadEntries(blogEntries)
  .then((entries) => console.log(entries));
```

Comment: I have following issue with this approach: ```WARNING in ./path/to/file/index.js 63:13-53
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./src/app.js```
 @ ./src/server-entry.js

Answer (score 1):

```
const Markdown = {}

for (let entry in blogEntries) {
  Markdown[entry] = require(`/static/blog/${entry}.md`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following link. It's essentially used the external library - `marked`, fetching the content, then rendering the content to the screen. Essentially, you can call multiple fetches for each file needed and render the content dynamically.

[How do I load a markdown file into a react component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928530/how-do-i-load-a-markdown-file-into-a-react-component)

Note: There is a proposal in the ECMAScript standard for a dynamic import. You can read more about this here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import

Comment: The question isn't about rendering markdown, it's about dynamically including static files.

Comment: Ah, but, as you can read, the OP wants to 'eventually' render Markdown.

Comment: Sorry, but the dynamic import() only works when you use browser-side import/export. It won't work with React's babel transpilation. Plus it's Chrome-only, and experimental.

Comment: I'm glad you can. The question is not just about dynamic imports, but dynamic imports && markdown. To alleviate your concern, I edited my answer since at some point in the future, it is likely possible to import dynamically.

Comment: Chris, as I said, it's a proposal that will most likely be adopted by the Babel and web browser community.