# Any easy way to import multiple image files at once in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I type the following for importing images. Need a short way to do this.

```
import banner1 from "./imgs/Banners/banner1.jpg"
import banner2 from "./imgs/Banners/banner2.jpg"
import banner3 from "./imgs/Banners/banner3.jpg"
import banner4 from "./imgs/Banners/banner4.jpg"
import banner5 from "./imgs/Banners/banner5.jpg"
import banner6 from "./imgs/Banners/banner6.jpg"
import banner7 from "./imgs/Banners/banner7.jpg"
import banner8 from "./imgs/Banners/banner8.jpg"
import banner9 from "./imgs/Banners/banner9.jpg"
.
.
.
import banner(n) from "./imgs/Banners/banner(n).jpg"
```

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52956474/create-a-loop-to-import-files-dynamically-in-react ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with react but is actually concerning the bundler that you use. What bundler do you use? parcel, webpack, rollup, etc?

Comment: An easy way is put all your image in public folder. then use as `src='path/from/public/to/img'`. Needn't import them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Since you are using webpack, have a look at [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-context) . You should be able to import all png files in `'./imgs/Banners'` to `images` variable. Then you can use image by `images["banner(n).png"]`.

```
function importAll(r) {
    let images = {};
    r.keys().map((item, index) => { images[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
    return images;
}

const images = importAll(require.context('./imgs/Banners', false, '/\.jpg/'));

<img src={images["banner1.png"]} />
```

- In another way, you can use a file dedicated to these imports :

`images.js` :

```
import banner1 from "./imgs/Banners/banner1.jpg"
import banner2 from "./imgs/Banners/banner2.jpg"
import banner3 from "./imgs/Banners/banner3.jpg"
import banner4 from "./imgs/Banners/banner4.jpg"
import banner5 from "./imgs/Banners/banner5.jpg"
import banner6 from "./imgs/Banners/banner6.jpg"
import banner7 from "./imgs/Banners/banner7.jpg"
import banner8 from "./imgs/Banners/banner8.jpg"
import banner9 from "./imgs/Banners/banner9.jpg"
.
.
.
import banner(n) from "./imgs/Banners/banner(n).jpg"

export default [
    banner1,
    banner2,
    ...
];
```

Then import this array in one line in other files :

```
import banners from './images';
```