# Webpack loader for .md file import for "react-markdown" npm library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, markdown

When i import a `.md` file , it gave me error, saying that it cannot read this particular `.md file syntax`,
I know there needs to be some kind of loader for it to parse the import, but when i looked online there was a loader called `'markdown-loader'` which was only for `marked` npm package.

I am using `react-markdown` package to read md files

```
/* eslint-disable react/prefer-stateless-function */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
import AppMarkdown from './posts/sample.md';

// import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class CardDetails extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { markdown: '' };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Get the contents from the Markdown file and put them in the React state, so we can reference it in render() below.
     fetch(AppMarkdown)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(text => this.setState({ markdown: text }));
  }

  render() {
    const { markdown } = this.state;
    return <ReactMarkdown source={markdown} />;
  }
}

CardDetails.propTypes = {};
export default CardDetails;
```

[image: error on console]

here's my markdown content `sample.md`

```
# React & Markdown App

- Benefits of using React... but...
- Write layout in Markdown!
```

i could not find package , i looked everywhere, do you know about the loader ?
Thankyou

Comment: you don't need any webpack plugins for that. Seems like your markdown code is wrong.

Comment: @demkovych i updated my question with error picture

Comment: I posted example using webpack loader "raw-loader" here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65744729/1418981

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to use raw-loader:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.md$/,
        use: 'raw-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: oh seems like raw-loader was commented out in my config lemme build the dll and get back to you

Comment: btw this line 
  fetch(AppMarkdown)
      .then(res => res.text())
      .then(text => this.setState({ markdown: text }));

seems to get my ```index.html content``` and set that content to `markdown` do you know why , i think i did pretty much everything the library said

Comment: sorry, I don't know. Try to move your file into the same directory or use `require` instead.

Comment: i moved it in the same directory , checked paths... , but the promise value that is being is returned is the index.html text , i  dont know what went wrong, i will debug it more , this is annoying lol

Comment: Try to use another plugin instead of react-markdown

Comment: some issue with es6 import , instead of fetch used async/await with commonjs require, it works, thanks for you help haha